# Is "add Xn, Xn, SP" valid in ARM64?

Tags: assembly, arm64

I have problems assembling `add x1, x1, sp`. From what I have read that should be possible in AArch64?

The following assembles correctly `add x1, sp, x1`

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, `add x1, x1, sp` is not an encodable AArch64 instruction.  The permitted scalar variants of the `add` instruction are:

```
ADD <Wd|WSP>, <Wn|WSP>, <Wm>{, <extend> {#<amount>}}
ADD <Xd|SP>, <Xn|SP>, <R><m>{, <extend> {#<amount>}}
ADD <Wd|WSP>, <Wn|WSP>, #<imm>{, <shift>}
ADD <Xd|SP>, <Xn|SP>, #<imm>{, <shift>}
ADD <Wd>, <Wn>, <Wm>{, <shift> #<amount>}
ADD <Xd>, <Xn>, <Xm>{, <shift> #<amount>}
```

Observe how for none of these variants `SP` is permitted as the third operand.

Comment: Thanks! You are right, I missed that limitation in the second operand